# Trouble with Python Pandas Merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am merging two datasets:

`th_users_clean` has 12,000 rows.
`th` has 207,917 rows.

I have performed several merge types (inner, left, etc.) but can only seem to maintain 207,917 rows. I really want the information from `th` to be added on to `th_users_clean`, meaning I want a resulting final merged table of 12,000 rows. Does anyone know what could be causing this problem?

Heads for each of the dataframes are below. I would like to merge them on `user_id`.
Final output should be 12,000 rows and 14 columns.

```
full_df = th.merge(th_users_clean, on = 'user_id')
```

```
th.head(2)

    time_stamp          user_id visited visits_7_days   adopted_users
0   2014-04-22 03:53:30     1     1         1.0            0
1   2013-11-15 03:45:04     2     1         1.0            0
```

```
th_users_clean.head(2)
        time_stamp    user_id   visited visits_7_days   adopted_users   creation_time   name                   email               creation_source  last_session_creation_time  opted_in_to_mailing_list    enabled_for_marketing_drip  org_id  invited_by_user_id
0   2014-04-22 03:53:30   1        1        1.0              0      2014-04-22 03:53:30 Clausen August  AugustCClausen@yahoo.com    GUEST_INVITE    2014-04-22 03:53:30               1                                0                   11    10803.0
```

Comment: please give a sample of your dataframes, at least which columns they have and how do you want to merge (common index? just concatenating?)

Answer (score 1):

You want to concatenate data-frames, not merge them. Concatenating is like appending to the end.

```
concat = pandas.concat([th, th_users_clean])
```

Output:

```
        time_stamp    user_id   visited visits_7_days   adopted_users   creation_time         name 
0   2014-04-22 03:53:30     1     1         1.0            0
1   2013-11-15 03:45:04     2     1         1.0            0 
2   2014-04-22 03:53:30     1     1         1.0            0      2014-04-22 03:53:30 Clausen August
```

Merging is adding the columns of `th_users_clean` to `th`.

For example, if you want the columns of `th_users_clean` to be merged to `th` on `time_stamp`;

```
merge = pandas.merge(th, th_users_clean, on='time_stamp')
```

Output:

```
    time_stamp    user_id   visited visits_7_days   adopted_users   creation_time         name 
0   2014-04-22 03:53:30     1     1         1.0            0      2014-04-22 03:53:30 Clausen Augus
1   2013-11-15 03:45:04     2     1         1.0            0
```

Here, the `time_stamp` from `th` is matched to `th_users_clean` and all the values in `th_users_clean` row is added to `th`.